# Why this Map return null value?

Tags: apex

I am posting a snippet of code, just want to know why this return null. When I do it the other way, making Map<Id,String> and making accountId as String then it return a value.

```
id accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test123');
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));
```

Comment: Likely to do with 15 vs 18 character ID representations.

Comment: As phil said its due to 15 and 18 digit Id representation , if you try to print your variable "accountId " you will notice its 18 digit

Comment: @PhilW got it, it was due to 15 vs 18 digit character. Just want to know then why  below code is not having null while fetching variable.       string accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<id,string> abcMap = new map<id,string>();
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test');
system.debug(accountId);
system.debug(abcMap);
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address this and fix your code, no need to convert IDs, simply use IDs in your map declaration instead of String:

```
map<id,string> abcMap = new map<id,string>();
```

**Corrected explanation on July 15**

The `Map` class uses the `hashCode()` method to compare elements and find a value based on a key. However, when working with IDs, a 15 or 18 characters ID are considered equal under certain conditions even though the strings are not strictly identical.

Comment: poz, thanks for your input, I am pasting my answer below after your comment so that community will get to know about this a bit more.

Comment: @RajaRay I'm considering recording a video that highlights your question and the answer a bit more in depth would that be ok with you?

Comment: sure np. Please let me know if the video will be on any platform where I can also get in detail.

Comment: Thanks, it will be hosted on YouTube around July 19. I'll post the link here when I have it.

Comment: A bit late but here's the video of my answer: https://youtu.be/QfEaGusD3EU?t=122

Answer (score 1):

Following are the Map Considerations:

- Unlike Java, Apex developers do not need to reference the algorithm that is used to implement a map in their declarations (for example, HashMap or TreeMap). Apex uses a hash structure for all maps.
- The iteration order of map elements is deterministic. You can rely on the order being the same in each subsequent execution of the same code. However, we recommend to always access map elements by key.
- A map key can hold the null value.
- Adding a map entry with a key that matches an existing key in the map
  overwrites the existing entry with that key with the new entry.
- ***Map keys of type String are case-sensitive. Two keys that differ only
  by the case are considered unique and have corresponding distinct Map
  entries. Subsequently, the Map methods, including put, get,
  containsKey, and remove treat these keys as distinct.***
- Uniqueness of map keys of user-defined types is determined by the
  equals and hashCode methods, which you provide in your classes.
  Uniqueness of keys of all other non-primitive types, such as sObject
  keys, is determined by comparing the objects’ field values.

So in your case the Id being considered as string while using it in Map and becomes case sensitive. However, if you try to use the id variable as it is in your map then it should work fine.

Also be noted about the salesforce Id, 15 vs 18 character ID representation.

Here is modified code:

```
id accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put(accountId,'test123');
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));
```

Demo code for understanding:

```
id accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
String accString = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put(accountId,'test123');
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','Stringtest123');
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));
system.debug(abcMap.get(accString));
```

Refer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) for more help

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Poz, pasting my analysis below

1. That's why below code give you value. Id in map is 18 digit but the string is of 15 digit, as you said, 15 and 18 digit  characters id are considered equal as it is using equal function to compare:::

   string accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
   map<id,string> abcMap = new map<id,string>();
   abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test');
   system.debug(accountId);
   system.debug(abcMap);
   system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));
2. But when I used below code, it will null will be printed because the Id here will be now of 18 digit and map will be having strict string value

id accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test');
system.debug(accountId);
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));

Answer (score 0):

> Issue related to Id on 15 vs 18 character ID representation as Phil said.

Your code should be consistent while using it. When use Id field, it will convert internally 18 digit character format( [Salesforce Id Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_id.htm) )

You can solve either using two different way as follows

1. Convert Id to 15 digit format before using it

```
id accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test123');
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId.to15()));
```

2. Using String data type as AccountId to store 15 digit

```
String accountId = '0010o00002svksw';
map<string,string> abcMap = new map<string,string>();
abcMap.put('0010o00002svksw','test123');
system.debug(abcMap.get(accountId));
```